# How to get the region format setting in Windows Phone 8.1 XAML APP

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, cultureinfo, win-universal-app

Since the introduction of the new WP 8.1 platform some changes were made to the CultureInfo class. CultureInfo.CurrentCulture used to return the region format setting. WP 8.1 seems to return the default language set in the Package.appxmanifest which makes little sence IMO. It is crucial for me to have region format. If there are other means of getting it I am looking for them.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [msdn article on CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture(v=vs.110).aspx), try using :

```
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name;
```

Have a look at this one too:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but sadly `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name` is not what I need

Comment: I think you need System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

Answer (score 0):

This might work :

```
CultureInfo cc;
regionalFrmt.Text = cc.NativeName;

regionalFrmt.Text = cc.NativeName;
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff637519(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Thanks but not it. I've edited my question title to clarify that we are talking specifically about Universal XAML WP apps